# how can I delete a node from hbox in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

```
package application;

import java.util.Date;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Logbook2 extends Application implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Logbook");

        BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
        
        Button add = new Button("+");

        Button remove = new Button("X");

        TextField textBox = new TextField();

        textBox.setPrefColumnCount(20);

        HBox hbox = new HBox(3, textBox, add, remove);
        
        border.setBottom(hbox);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(border, 300, 300);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        add.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                                
                Label l = new Label();

                String str = new Date().toString();

                l.setText(str + " " + textBox.getText());
                
                VBox vbox = new VBox(3, l);
                
                border.setTop(vbox);

            }
        });

        remove.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                
                try {
                    while (border.getChildren().size() != 0) {
                        hbox.getChildren().remove(3);
                    }
                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

                }

            }

        });
        
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

}
```

This is how it looks ->

[image]

I am facing 3 issues:

1. I added java but when I click on "+" to add python, it replaces java with python instead of adding python.
2. When I click on "X", it should delete all inputs but nothing happens.
3. After I add a text, I want it to disappear from TextField. I tried calling setText() method at the end of handle() method; but then add function doesn't work.

Comment: I think you want to add `vbox` to `hbox` instead overwriting the top element of `border` using `border.setTop(vbox)`. If you do this, you can also just remove all children from `hbox` when the `X`-button is pressed.

Comment: I started learning JavaFX yesterday so not really sure if that's what I want. I just want to add the text to the top and textbox, "+" and "X" buttons to stay at the bottom.  And of course, all the buttons to perform correctly.

Comment: `BorderPane#setTop` overwrites the top of the BorderPane element. I don't think you want to do this.

Comment: You may want to consider using a `ListView<String>` (possibly in the center instead of the top) and then just add/clear its items (e.g. `listView.getItems().add(...)` and `listView.getItems().clear()`). Also, I recommend using the "new" `java.time` API added in Java 8 instead of the old API (i.e. instead of `Date`).

Comment: 1. You are calling `setTop(…)` and passing in a new `VBox`. This will replace whatever’s in the top of the border pane (probably an existing `VBox`) with the new `VBox` which contains a single label. You probably want to add the label to an existing `VBox`. 2. There are three elements in your `HBox`, indexed 0, 1, and 2. You try to remove the element at index 3. Furthermore, you completely squash the resulting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` (**never** do this), so you don’t even see the error message. If you want to remove everything, get rid of the loop and just call `clear()` on the list.

Comment: Since you just started learning `JavaFX` the other day, I would recommend against `implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>` for the `Application` class.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those cases where the poor programming style and bad naming of elements made everything so complicated that it became very difficult for the OP keep track of how things are supposed to work.

Refactoring started off by removing all the blank lines, and letting the IDE refactor the  anonymous EventHandler classes to lambda expressions.  Then everything that didn't actually need to be instantiated as a variable was in-lined. Everything left was renamed to something that made it clear what it was.

The "implements EventHandler" doesn't make any sense, as the Application should be the start point for the JavaFX engine.  So that, plus the do-nothing `handle()` method were removed.

Finally, the code was rearranged so that the layout was at the top followed by the actions and then the Scene/Stage configuration.

Then it was clear how to fix the actual issue.

Basically this involved creating a VBox in the layout (called "resultsBox") and putting it in the top of the BorderPane.  The action handler for the "+" Button now adds a new label to resultsBox and clears the TextField.  The action handler for the "X" Button clears the contents of the resultsBox:

```
public class Logbook2 extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        Button addButton = new Button("+");
        Button removeButton = new Button("X");
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setPrefColumnCount(20);
        VBox resultsBox = new VBox(3);
        borderPane.setBottom(new HBox(3, textField, addButton, removeButton));
        borderPane.setTop(resultsBox);
        addButton.setOnAction(evt -> {
            resultsBox.getChildren().add(new Label(new Date() + " " + textField.getText()));
            textField.setText("");
        });
        removeButton.setOnAction(evt -> resultsBox.getChildren().clear());
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(borderPane, 300, 300));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Logbook");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```